# Feed cache fallback - A feed could not be found

Tags: cache, feed, simplepie

Trying to refactor a feed plugin to fallback on cache if source is unavailable (ex: for maintenance).

Started using `fetch_feed($url);` which affords more flexibility in terms of cache. But unsure of how to structure the fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking at it from a very low layer POV. `fetch_feed` provides caching so you will not need to wait for a response on possibly every page load. Therefor, as long as there is a cache you are unlikely to even **want** a message to be sent and obviously you are not handling any actual result. It is unlikely that you will want to hurt your server with a faster refresh rate just to be able to properly detect the conditions on the other side.

What you should do is to handle the situation of not getting a reply, which is probably equal to empty feed, to supply the defaults you want.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something like so:
`if(is_wp_error($rss)){
  $rss = get_transient('my_rss_feed'); 
 }`

Comment: So I've read that fetch_feed is cached 12hrs by default, But what if I want the cache to expire every 30mins, but have a fallback that lasts 12hrs. Is it possible to have 2 caches? If I set my own transient, will the default cache still work?

Comment: I am not sure about the minimal interval you can set for the `fetch_feed` caching, but I guess it is possible to set it to 30 min. Than at you higher level you can set a transient with whatever is your default and set it to expire after 12 hours.